# Laravel, 2 forms on the same page/URL posting to individual Routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In my laravel site, I have a page with an existing form submission (working) and I'm trying to add another form but the refresh on submit goes to a blank page

I have a route set for the POST of each form, but the problem comes from the fact that I have 2 POSTs to the same effective url 'Route::post('user'

Each POST calls a different function in the controller and I need both forms to be on the same page/url (manager/user) but I'm not sure how to change this so that they both work here.

If I comment out the route for manager.user.create, then the store submission works just fine again.

```
    Route::post('user', 'user\userManagerController@store')
        ->name('manager.user');

    Route::post('user', 'user\userManagerController@create')
        ->name('manager.user.create');


    {!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' => route('manager.user')))  !!}

    {!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' => route('manager.user.create')))  !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define two endpoints with the same verb and URI.
You may try this:

```
Route::post('user', 'user\userManagerController@store')
    ->name('manager.user');

Route::post('anotherURI', 'user\userManagerController@create')
    ->name('manager.user.create');


{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' => route('manager.user')))  !!}

{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' => route('manager.user.create')))
```

Comment: so if the url for the page with both forms is page.com/manager/user and I make one endpoint 'user' and the other 'user/create' then it will still work?

Comment: You have to separate between the GET endpoint which you probably have and the POST endpoints you've just shared.

You may have several forms in a page, all you need to make sure each form is being submitted to another URL.

For your question, yes, if you use a different one like one user and the other one is user/create - then it will work.